# Эндпоинт для регистрации через REST API Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, users

Как на вордпресс зарегистрировать пользователя посредством rest api?
В документации в разделе users нашел эндпоинты для чего угодно, но не регистрации. (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/)

Есть метод create user, но это не то, для этого нужны права администратора + при регистрации можно назначить роль, а надо чтобы любой пользователь мог зарегистрировать.

Видел на форумах советуют /wp/v2/users/register, но он не работает, видимо свой эндпоинт добавить надо, но может есть готовое уже, более безопаснее чем самописный.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно изучил вопрос, то готовых методов нет. Поэтому есть 2 способа решения:

1. Добавить свой собственный эндпоинт. Как это сделать можно прочитать в документации или в статьях в интернете.
2. Найти готовый плагин, который реализует данную функциональность.

В данном случае я нашел решение в виде готового плагина
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-user/